# How to correctly show uploaded files inline (module media integraed with Wysiwyg)?

Tags: drupal-7, wysiwyg, media

Drupal 7.15
Modules: media 7.1.2, mediaelement.js, Wysiwyg with ckeditor.

My process:

1.admin/config/content/wysiwyg/profile  >  enabled "Media browser" in "Buttons and plugins"
2.admin/config/content/formats          >  enabled "admin/config/content/formats"
3.add content > click button "add media" to add mp3 and a picture to the body

But it shows wrong. The page source show:

[[{"type":"media","view_mode":"default","fid":"99","attributes":{"alt":"","class":"media-image"}}]]

[[{"type":"media","view_mode":"default","fid":"40","attributes":{"alt":"","class":"media-image"}}]]

Meanwhile, files work well in fields in Content types.

Best Regards.

Hugo

Answer (score 2):

1. Navigate to admin/config/content/formats
2. Click the 'configure' link for the text format that is enabled on your WYSIWYG editor
3. Check the *Convert Media tags to markup* checkbox
4. Save the form
5. Crack open a beer, that was hard work

Comment: I find it's necessary to enable image and audio in "Home » Administration » Configuration » Media » File types". But after File Type audio is enabled, all buttons of editor diappeared. Now how can I deal with this problem?

Comment: No idea, you'll need to open a new question for that one

Comment: Please check this link with pictures:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196997/editor-buttons-all-disppear-using-inline-editingdrupal7mediawysiwygckeditor

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Clive's answer, it should be noted that overriding rendering in template files can totally ignore the "convert media tags to markup" setting if you render the wrong property.

```
<?php print render($node->body['und'][0]['safe_value']); ?>
```

'safe_value' will maintain the rendering, where as just 'value' will not. If you are uncertain what the object properties hold, you can always do something like this in your template file to crawl through the insultingly huge node object yourself...

```
<pre>
<?php print_r($node); ?>
</pre>
```

Get ready to be more confused though. Drupal loves to assault you with objects of extraordinary length. It can sometimes be hard to follow the chain down to just what you need. Don't be afraid to do it slowly, and print_r in progressive order till you are left looking at something that makes sense.

```
<pre>
<?php print_r($node->body); ?>
</pre>
```

hmmm... that's too big.

```
<pre>
<?php print_r($node->body['und']); ?>
</pre>
```

Ok, getting cleaner

```
<pre>
<?php print_r($node$node->body['und'][0]); ?>
</pre>
```

Aah. got it. ok I can use this.